# How can a Sum method return null in C# linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The definition of Sum function in Linq is `public static double? Sum(this IEnumerable<double?> source)` But I noticed this function never returns null even you sum a list with all null values.
For example: `new List<double?>(){null,null}.Sum()` or `new List<double?>(){0,null}.Sum()` both returns 0 but not null.
The question is:
Can Sum function returns null? If can, how to return null, if cannot why the definition of Sum function is "double?" but not "double"

Comment: Its functionality is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-sum(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-nullable((system-double)))))) (see Remarks). So in short: no, it can't return null.

Comment: I have no idea why that signature returns a nullable. The implementation agrees with the documentation: it will never return null in practice. [Stephen Toub agrees](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29508#issuecomment-491344812)

Answer (score 1):

seems MS designed it, but we can use aggreate() and use "+" to impelment the "Sum" for double? list, and it can return null if any one is null in the list:

list.Aggreate((a, b) => a+b);